# "Permitting for" or just "permitting"?

Tags: word-usage

Is the phrase "permitting for" okay to use in the same way "allowing for" would be when not working on a verb?

> This does that, permitting for fewer those.
>
> This does that, permitting fewer those.

Comment: The latter is correct. *Allowing for* something to take place; *allowing* something to take place; *permitting* something to take place. *Permission to*. It depends on context.

Comment: I think you want *fewer* ***of*** *those*, here. And no, *permitting for* does not sound correct to me, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes when we go too abstract, it becomes harder to analyze the question.  Neither of your statements holds as is.

Let's look at specific implementations:

**A nuclear weapon** does **terrible damage to a part of the Earth**, permitting for fewer **countries**.

**A nuclear weapon** does **terrible damage to a part of the Earth**, permitting fewer **countries**.

Neither of those "flow" (suggesting other noun/verb/noun combinations will also not flow) in either of the structures provided.

**A nuclear weapon** does **terrible damage to a part of the Earth**, so fewer **countries** *will exist when more nuclear weapons are used*.

But, adjusting the gerund ("permitting") with a coordinating conjunction ("so") and then completing the sentence via a relative pronoun ("when") tying the predicate to the subject of the sentence flows much better (unlike this sentence which seems overly complex!)

I try to keep it simple: If I can read it to myself out loud and it sounds natural, then that's the phrasing I should go with... and figure the punctuation out after the fact.

EDIT: And, yes, I ended the sentence with "are used", leaving it to imply "are used to damage parts of the Earth" -- can I chalk that up to slightly lazy? ;)